# A class with toString() can be used as a string, but how to convince the TypeScript compiler?

Tags: typescript, type-safety, type-coercion

My class implements `toString()` to allow me to use any instance conveniently as a property name when building up other objects. The TypeScript compiler though is not convinced and outputs: `a computed property name must be of type 'string'`
How can I declare my class in a way that satisfies the compiler?

```js
class Foo {
  name: string  
  constructor(name: string) { this.name = name; }
  toString() { return this.name; }
}
```

which can be used thus:

```js
const myFoo = new Foo('Clytemnestra');
const someObject = { [myFoo]: 'she murders Agamemnon'};
```

Currently the last line above produces the aforementioned type error.

Comment: Use `[myFoo.toString()]`? Given virtually everything can be coerced to a string, _"honoring it would hide more bugs than enable valid patterns"_ per https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14207.

Comment: One of the biggest advantages of using a static type system is avoiding the problems created by the exact sort of implicit conversion you're using. You're going to have to make the conversion explicit.

Comment: Jon and Jared are right. Also you did not even include valid Typescript in your example.

Answer (score 0):

### you can't

You can't "convince" the Typescript static type checker to ignore an object's type and rely on the coerced type -- that would defeat the whole purpose of static type checking.

### but you could...

0verride the statically determined type by changing the offending line thusly:

```js
const someObject = { [myFoo as unknown as string ]: 'she murders Agamemnon'};
```

That smells bad immediately.

Ok, how about:

```js
const someObject = { [ myFoo.toString() ]: 'she murders Agamemnon'};
```

This is slightly better, as you are explicitly doing the "coercing" to string.

But both of these ultimately are a bad idea. Any object can be coerced into string, the default value often being "[object Object]". Relying on the `toString()` method undermines type safety. So you're again defeating the purpose of static type checking. You must ask: why am I using Typescript?

#### instead, a more type safe approach

```js
class Subject {
  name: string
  city: string
  constructor(name: string, city: string) { 
    this.name = name
    this.city = city
  }
}

const vengefulWife = new Subject('Clytemnestra', 'Mycenae');

const summaries = new Map<Subject, string>()
summaries.set(vengefulWife, 'she murders Agamemnon')


for (const [key, value] of summaries) {
  console.log(`${key.name} of ${key.city}: ${value}`);
}
```

Because Typescript knows the type of `key`, it recognizes the
references to `key.name` and `key.city` as valid

Comment: I want to do this because I have a class that is almost a string but not quite. The code would be so clean if I could use my string wrapper as a string.

Comment: I need more details. Create a new question and link to it here and I will take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/pull/500/files#diff-3294a832ea2276e554177e0b3007cc2d401c082912c7fbde49fa09141bf1aed1 (you'll have to click "Load diff" on utils.ts)

Comment: When I said "I want to do this" I just meant I want to coerce a class with a `.toString()` to a string like this `"foo" + instanceOfThatClass` which it turns out TypeScript actually lets me do, so the first sentence in your answer is misleading, especially to anyone that doesn't read the question like me (which is basically everyone)

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy Typescript "lets" you do that because it's legal Javascript, which is always legal TS. In JS, `+` operand [has special rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition), and even then it's not really "string coercion" but "primitive coercion" which *might* use `toString()`. You can't call `function(string, string)` with `"foo" + instanceOfClassWithToString`, so I wasn't misleading. The `+` operand is a very special case, more like a function that takes (any, any), calls each value's `[@@toPrimitive]()`, and then decides what to do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. When I said "let" I mean that I didn't get a type error that I'm adding a non-string to a string. No, I didn't, since you were answering a different question, not my question, I just told you that your answer to that question confused me, whether or not you want to do anything with that information is up to you.